# how to put limit on number of selected items for multiselect Listbox of gwt?

Tags: gwt, listbox, selection, multi-select

I need to select max three items from multiselect listbox of GWT. How can I achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is not any method in the widget to limit that, hence you have to write your own code in a handler. For instance you can add a click-handler and count the number of items selected, if it is over the limit you have to deselect the clicked element. You have to consider though other ways to select the element like touch or keyboard handlers.

Maybe you could be interested on using a nice widget which already comes with this functionality: [gwtquery choosen](http://jdramaix.github.io/gwtchosen/)